# Хэширование логина и почты для хранения в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных, хеширование

Стоит ли для хранения в БД хэшировать помимо пароля ещё и имя пользователя, его почту? Или не заморачиваться и хэшировать только пароль?

Comment: На почту обычно периодически присылают какие-нибудь уведомления, так что хэшировать её как-то странно

Comment: Из хэша (почти) невозможно восстановить исходное значение. То есть пользователь в итоге лишится своей почты.

Comment: А, вы имеете в виду адрес почтового ящика? Не содержимое? Но в любом случае, вы не сможете потом сами получить доступ к этому адресу, если, например, пользователь забудет пароль и захочет получить новый на почту.

Answer (score 0):

Если хэшировать только пароль, то видно будет где одинаковые пароли.
Хэшировать стоит пароль+что-нибудь, а это что-нибудь можно хранить рядом открыто.

Answer (score 0):

Пароли хешируют для того, чтобы злоумышленник не мог воспользоваться ими, даже если получит доступ к БД с этими паролями.

А если захешировать имя пользователя, то как к нему обращаться? Обычно же имя выводится где-то на сайте. А из хеша его восстановить невозможно. И тогда будет вместо имени строка хеша. Некрасиво.

Аналогично с почтой. Если захешировать её, то станет невозможно посылать письма пользователям. Например, если юзер забудет свой пароль, то новый временный высылается ему на почту. С хешем это невозможно.

Comment: ну по идее можно ассиметрично зашифровать, а потом когда из бд брать хэш в читабельную строку. Типо такого, но мне кажется лишнее будет, не?

Comment: @ИванИванов - шифрование и хэширование - разные вещи. Шифрование обратимо. Хэширование - нет.